# Required request part 'file' is not present in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-restcontroller, spring-rest

**I checked all of the simular posts and still couldnt find the solution.**

Problem is **Required request part 'file' is not present** in test class.

I want to upload a file and save it to the database. Here is my rest controller `@RestController`:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/upload")
public ResponseEntity<LogoDto> uploadLogo(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile multipartFile) {
   return ResponseEntity.ok(logoService.createLogo(multipartFile));
}
```

and my test class:

```
@Test
public void createLogo2() throws Exception {
    String toJsonLogoDto = new Gson().toJson(logoDto);
    MockMultipartFile file = new MockMultipartFile("path", "url", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, image);
    LogoDto response = LogoDataTest.validLogoDto();
    Mockito.when(logoServiceMock.createLogo(Mockito.any(MultipartFile.class))).thenReturn(response);
    mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.multipart("/brand-icon/upload")
            .file(file)
            .content(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
            .characterEncoding(CharEncoding.UTF_8))
            .andDo(MockMvcResultHandlers.print())
            .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk());
}
```

and my `application.yml` looks like this:

```
spring:
  servlet:
    multipart:
      enabled: true
      max-file-size: 2MB
      max-request-size: 10MB
```

I tried to add consumes in my @PostMapping;
try to set literally every MediaTypes.. still get an error.

I appreciate all of your answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

issue is in declaration of `MockMultipartFile`, first parameter should match controller `@RequestParam` param. So, in your case, should be:

```
MockMultipartFile file = new MockMultipartFile("file", "url", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, image);
```

Also, I recommend to update your controller method to the following one:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/upload", consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<LogoDto> uploadLogo(@RequestPart("file") MultipartFile multipartFile) {
    ...
}
```